# UISwipeGestureRecognizer swift 3 measuring velocity

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Im trying to determine the speed of an animation basted on the velocity of a swipe. I know UIPanGestureRecgnizer has a velocity(in: View) function but haven't been able to find anything similar in the UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Know how I can do this?

Comment: You can calculate the time different and x-position difference between `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`.
With this you can calculate "pixels per second". Thus calculating the velocity.
You can check out the `UIResponder` documentation for `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`.

Comment: Why not use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`???

Comment: Didn't find a great answer to that so I switched to UIPanGestureRecognizer and.... problem solved